# Moments of all orders exist but mgf does not exist.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I was trying to find to find an example of a probability density function whose moments of all orders exist but its $mgf$ i.e. The Moment generating function does not exist. I only know the definitions, so I could not proceed anywhere. Thanks in advance for help...

Comment: You essentially need a PDF which falls off faster than any power but slower than any exponential. One example is the one with CDF $=\mathbb{E}\left[X \le t\right] = 1 - e^{-\sqrt{t}}$ for $t \ge 0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function